# Check user log issue

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a header with login/register options if the user is not logged in, and if they are then profile, inbox and account options. I am using `<?php include_once "../scripts/checkuserlog.php"; ?>` at the top of the header, with `<?php echo $logOptions; ?>` in the div I want the words to show up in. The error I am getting is "warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/ssdotcom/public_html/index.php:6) in /home/ssdotcom/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 2" which is jibberish to me, line two is an opening div tag... here is the code for the header file:

```
<?php include_once "../scripts/checkuserlog.php"; ?>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="http://sunnahspace.com/index.php"><img src="../img/logo.jpg" width="500" height="100" alt="SunnahSpace"/></a></div>
  <div id="header_menu">
    <div><?php echo $logOptions; ?></div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu_bar">
    <div id="menu_text_container">
<div class="menu_text">
        <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">feeds</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text">
        <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">blogs</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text">
          <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">forums</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text">
        <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">chat</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text">
          <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">sunnahversity</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text">
        <span class="menu_text_span"><a href="#">suggestions</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_text_right">
        <span class="menu_text_span_right"><a href="#">settings</a></span>
        <span class="menu_text_span_right"><a href="#">about</a></span>
        <span class="menu_text_span_right"><a href="#">home</a></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the checkuserlog script:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; // Connect to database
$dyn_www = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$logOptions = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION['idx'])) { 
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['idCookie'])) {
     $logOptions = '<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/register.php">Register</a>
     &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/login.php">Log In</a>';
   }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['idx'])) { 

    $decryptedID = base64_decode($_SESSION['idx']);
    $id_array = explode("p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234", $decryptedID);
    $logOptions_id = $id_array[1];

   //private message check:
    $sql_pm_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id='$logOptions_id' AND opened='0' LIMIT 1");
    $num_new_pm = mysql_num_rows($sql_pm_check);
    if ($num_new_pm > 0) {
        $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="../img/pm2.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
    } else {
        $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="../img/pm1.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
    }
    // show results
    $logOptions = $PM_envelope . ' &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <!--<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '">Home</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
    <a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/profile.php?id=' . $logOptions_id . '">Profile</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="dc">
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Account &nbsp; <img src="../images/darr.gif" width="10" height="5" alt="Account Options" border="0"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/edit_profile.php">Account Options</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_inbox.php">Inbox Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_sentbox.php">Sent Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
';
//set cookies:
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['idCookie'])) {

    $decryptedID = base64_decode($_COOKIE['idCookie']);
    $id_array = explode("nm2c0c4y3dn3727553", $decryptedID);
    $userID = $id_array[1]; 
    $userPass = $_COOKIE['passCookie'];
    // Get their user first name to set into session var
    $sql_uname = mysql_query("SELECT username, email FROM myMembers WHERE id='$userID' AND password='$userPass' LIMIT 1");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql_uname);
    if ($numRows == 0) {
    //kill cookies if set
        setcookie("idCookie", '', time()-42000, '/');
        setcookie("passCookie", '', time()-42000, '/');
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_uname)){ 
        $username = $row["username"];
        $useremail = $row["email"];
    }

    $_SESSION['id'] = $userID; 
    $_SESSION['idx'] = base64_encode("g4p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234$userID");
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['useremail'] = $useremail;
    $_SESSION['userpass'] = $userPass;

    $logOptions_id = $userID;
    mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET last_log_date=now() WHERE id='$logOptions_id'"); 
    $sql_pm_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id='$logOptions_id' AND opened='0' LIMIT 1");
    $num_new_pm = mysql_num_rows($sql_pm_check);
    if ($num_new_pm > 0) {
        $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="../images/pm2.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
    } else {
        $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="../images/pm1.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
    }
    // Ready the output for this logged in user
     $logOptions = $PM_envelope . ' &nbsp; &nbsp;
     <!--<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '">Home</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
     <a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/profile.php?id=' . $logOptions_id . '">Profile</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="dc">
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Account &nbsp; <img src="../images/darr.gif" width="10" height="5" alt="Account Options" border="0"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/edit_profile.php">Account Options</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_inbox.php">Inbox Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_sentbox.php">Sent Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 2 of checkuserlog.php is session_start(). What it is complaining about is that it is unable to set the session cookie in the header since some output has already been sent from your index.php.

To avoid this problem make sure that your checkuserlog.php is included before line 6 of index.php

Comment: This is the beginning of my index: 

<!--[if IE]>
<script> window.location='pages/ie-bds-israel-n-supporters.php'; </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="margin:0;background-color:#333;">
<div id="header_container">
<?php include_once "pages/header.php" ?>
</div>

Comment: session_start() must be called before anything is output by your script. Even if you have an `echo " ";` somewhere, then the cookie headers cannot be sent. Move the `include_once(...checkuserlog.php)` to the top of index.php. See if that works.

Comment: it made the error disappear however the text is not appearing now.

Comment: Should have said copy `include_once(..checkuserlog.php)` to index.php. If you have removed it from header.php, put the include back. So the variable `$logOptions` is available to it.

Comment: ok, now i get these 4 errors:

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 54

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php:54) in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 57

Comment: and: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php:54) in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 58

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php:54) in /home/ssdotcom/public_html/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 59

Comment: The issue is your setcookie call on line 57. That is attempting to write headers, when your session start has already started the headers. Cookies must be set in the header, therefore before your page sends any kind of HTML output. Have a look at ob_start - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php.

Comment: @Nathan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3006/discussion-between-arunkumar-and-nathan)

Comment: Ok, what i did was delete session_start and replaced it with ob_start, and now the menu is available but with the error "Notice: Undefined index: post_code in /home/ssdotcom/scripts/checkuserlog.php on line 4" with this being line 4 of checkuserlog

ini_set('display_errors', '1');